# Record grouping and aggregation

Tags: cobol

I have a fixed record file with several millions of records containing sales for several thousands customers. I need to generate file with one record for each customer containing customer id, sales count and sales total.

I've just started to learn COBOL and I do not have idea what is a "COBOL way" to do that.

Obvious way in other programming languages will be to use some kind of map, but COBOL lacks such structures. COBOL arrays is out of question from performance reasons.

Other solution that comes to my mind is utilizing database, but it seems overkill for such trivial task.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Karbi79, I kinda have a hard time understanding your question. To me it sounds like this could be solved without COBOL since you're talking about files but to be honest I never used COBOL. Anyway, maybe the manual will help: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=languages-cobol

Comment: > COBOL arrays is out of question from performance reasons.

COBOL table handling is quite fast, especially because it is fixed-length (for use lengths use `OCCURS UNBOUNDED` and assign the memory dynamically.
You then specify the key(s) in the table definition and use `SORT` once after the data is load, if the order isn't correct, then you have everything in order and can use `SEARCH ALL` for real fast access.

Depending on how the structures are you possibly get best results with the external `SORT` (check the manual).

Comment: Sort the input file by customer (if not already sorted).  Read input file, adding sales total by customer.  When customer changes, write customer row.  No arrays or maps are needed.  Just a WORKING STORAGE area to sum the sales.

Comment: From the description it could be done without COBOL just using your available SORT-tool.

Comment: Don’t kid yourself that you can write COBOL code that is faster than the built in operations. I had a customer once who insisted that his homegrown multi pass two-way sort-merge was faster than my built in 11-way sort-merge. Couldn’t convince him. He wasted several weeks on it. It wasn’t faster. It was. *consderably* slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not stress this enough. If this is a *one-time* program or even run once a month, using the COBOL `SORT` should be preferred to spending time making it faster.

---

This method is similar to an "unordered map".

Create two tables: a "hash pointer table" (HPT) with more entries than there are customers (a prime number is preferred and the more entries the better for the distribution of hash values) and a variable length (ODO) "record table" (RT) large enough to hold records for all customers that may be present.

The HPT consists of an integer value where zero means no records for that value while a positive integer is used as a subscript to the record table.

The RT entries consist of two parts: an integer pointing to the next entry in a linked list (LLP) and a group containing the record fields (customer id, sales count, and sales total). The linked list is used for overflow and should be quite short – only a few records.

An integer RTP is used to point to the next available RT entry. The initial value is zero. It is also used to set the length of the RT. (OCCURS DEPENDING ON RTP)

As each record is read, the customer id is "hashed" to an integer within the number of entries in the HPT. This involves operations on the characters of the customer id, a `MOD` operation for the size of the HPT, and an `ADD` one.

To insert or accumulate values, first use the hashed value to access the HPT.

If the HPT entry is zero, insert the record by adding one to the RPT, move the RPT to the HPT entry for that hash value, move zero to the LLP for the RTP, move the customer id and sales amount to the RT entry and 1 to the count.

If the HPT entry is not zero, use the value of the HPT entry to follow the linked list in the RT to determine if a customer record exists (matching customer id). If the record exists, add one to the count and add the sales amount to the sales total. If the record does not exist, (the LLP is zero) create a new entry for the RT as before moving the RTP to the LLP of the last record in the linked list rather than the HPT entry.

After all records have been processed, the table will consist of RTP entries. Sort the table using an in-memory sort on customer id and output the values.

This method should require no more than a few megabytes of storage.

---

A few caveats.

This method is sensitive to the distribution of values from the hash function.

Performance is slowed if the more frequent accesses go to the end of the linked lists.

As the number of customers grows, table sizes will need to grow and that may cause distribution problems with the values from the hash function.

---

I only used this method once — over twenty years ago in a word count speed challenge. The challenge was how fast a program could count the number of distinct words in a large text file. It was very fast and much faster than other methods. It has some similarities to this problem.

It took several tries to get the program *tuned* for it to run really fast which I why I suggest staying with the standard `SORT`. It works and is more easily understood by others.

---

I wrote a program to demonstrate how this may be done. Since the question mentioned "several millions of records" and "several thousands customers", I created a test file with about 4 million records and about 27 thousand customers. I used a random number on each record to simulate date/time and sorted the test file into that sequence.

I also wrote a program sorting the input file by customer id for comparison. Both programs created identical outputs. but the hashing solution ran about 12 times faster on my old COBOL system.

Code:

```
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select cust-txns assign "z:custtxns.dat"
           organization sequential
           .
       select summ-list assign "z:summhash.txt"
           organization line sequential
           .
   data division.
   file section.
   fd cust-txns.
   01 cust-rec.
     02 cust-dt comp pic 9(8).
     02 cust-id pic x(8).
     02 cust-sale-amt pic 9(4)v99.
   fd summ-list.
   01 summ-rec.
     02 summ-id pic x(8).
     02 summ-cnt pic zzz9.
     02 summ-amt pic z,zz9.99.
   working-storage section.
   01 start-time pic 9(8).
   01 end-time pic 9(8).
   01 n comp-5 pic 9(8).
   01 cust-cnt comp-5 pic 9(8) value 0.
   01 hash-num comp-5 pic 9(8) value 0.
   01 .
     02 hash-id pic x(8).
     02 redefines hash-id.
       03 hash-1 comp pic 9(8).
       03 hash-2 comp pic 9(8).
  *> a prime value selected for efficient hashing
   78 hash-mod value 54983.
   01 hash-value comp-5 pic 9(8) value 0.
   01 discard comp-5 pic 9(16) value 0.
   01 curr-llp comp-5 pic 9(8) value 0.
   01 work-rec.
     02 work-llp comp-5 pic 9(8).
     02 work-id pic x(8).
     02 work-cnt comp-5 pic 9(8).
     02 work-sales comp-5 pic 9(6)v99.
  *> the hash table size is about twice the number of customers
   01 hash-lookup.
     02 hash-entry comp-5 pic 9(8) value 0 occurs hash-mod.
  *> required on my system for issues with crossing boundaries
   78 mem-fill value 65535 - next.
   01 pic x(mem-fill).
  *> less that 27000 customers expected
   01 cust-tab.
     02 cust-entry occurs 0 to 30000 depending cust-cnt.
       03 cust-llp comp-5 pic 9(8).
       03 cust-name pic x(8).
       03 cust-txn-cnt comp-5 pic 9(8).
       03 cust-total-sales comp-5 pic 9(6)v99.
  *> for the 64k boundary issue
       78 cust-fill value 12.
       03 pic x(cust-fill).
   procedure division.
       accept start-time from time
       open input cust-txns
       perform until exit
           read cust-txns
           at end
               exit perform
           not end
               perform count-record
           end-read
       end-perform
       close cust-txns
       perform print-report
       accept end-time from time
       display "Start time: " start-time
       display "  End time: " end-time
       stop run
       .
   count-record.
  *> place data into a temporary record
       move 0 to work-llp
       move cust-id to work-id
       move 1 to work-cnt
       move cust-sale-amt to work-sales
  *> get the hash-value
       perform hash-proc
  *> add the record if this is the first with that hash-value
       if hash-entry (hash-value) = 0
           add 1 to cust-cnt
           move work-rec to cust-entry (cust-cnt)
           move cust-cnt to hash-entry (hash-value)
       else
           perform search-existing
       end-if
       .
   search-existing.
  *> set the head of a linked list
       move hash-entry (hash-value) to curr-llp
  *> follow the links to the last record or an existing record
       perform until
           cust-llp (curr-llp) = 0
         or cust-name (curr-llp) = work-id
           move cust-llp (curr-llp) to curr-llp
       end-perform
  *> if an existing record update
       if cust-name (curr-llp) = work-id
           add 1 to cust-txn-cnt (curr-llp)
           add work-sales to cust-total-sales (curr-llp)
       else
  *> add new record to end of linked list
           add 1 to cust-cnt
           move cust-cnt to cust-llp (curr-llp)
           move work-rec to cust-entry (cust-cnt)
       end-if
       .
   hash-proc.
       move work-id to hash-id
       compute discard = hash-1 * 17 + hash-2
  *> this is a MOD function but faster on this system
       divide discard by hash-mod
           giving discard remainder hash-value
       add 1 to hash-value
       .
   print-report.
  *> in-memory sort for the approx 27000 customers
       sort cust-entry ascending cust-name
  *>
       open output summ-list
       perform varying n from 1 by 1
       until n > cust-cnt
           move cust-name (n) to  summ-id
           move cust-txn-cnt (n) to summ-cnt
           move cust-total-sales (n) to summ-amt
           write summ-rec
       end-perform
       close summ-list
       .
```

Comment: FWIW, I wrote two C# programs, one with `SortedDictionary`, and the other with `Hashtable`, that being closest to the COBOL code, above. `SortedDictionary` took twice as long, while `Hashtable` was about four seconds faster (31s vs 27s).

Comment: It seems like mainframe is capable of sorting my input file in tens of seconds. It will be scheduled once a day in relatively quiet period, so no worries. However, your solution using "hash arrays" is very efficient and I will be using it for larger data sets. Thank You very much for this contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solution with **acceptable** performance. It comes to me that COBOL has extremely efficient SORT implementation, especially external SORT on mainframes. Sorting 10GB data set with 10M records, using 1GB of RAM, takes less then one minute on laptop PC. I haven't tested it on mainframe yet, but I assume it will be much faster.

Here is my program in IBM dialect:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TOTALS.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT TX-FILE ASSIGN TO POS40TXN
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
           ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT SORTED-FILE ASSIGN TO SORTED
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
           ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT TMP-FILE ASSIGN TO TMP.
       SELECT TOTALS-FILE ASSIGN TO TOTALS
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
           ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  TX-FILE
       RECORDING MODE IS F.
   01 TX-REC PIC X(1000).
   FD  SORTED-FILE
       RECORDING MODE IS F.
  * ONLY IMPORTANT FIELDS ARE MAPPED
   01 TXN-REC.
     05 FILLER            PIC X(85).
     05 TXN-CLIENT        PIC X(15).
     05 FILLER            PIC X(88).
     05 TXN-AMOUNT        PIC S9(12).
     05 FILLER            PIC X(800).
     
   SD  TMP-FILE.
   01.
  * ONLY FIELDS USING IN SORT ARE MAPPED
     05 FILLER             PIC X(85).
     05 TMP-CLIENT         PIC X(15).
     05 FILLER             PIC X(900).
   FD  TOTALS-FILE
       RECORDING MODE IS F.
   01  BATCH-REC.
       05 CLIENT-CLIENT     PIC X(15).
       05 CLIENT-TXN-CNT    PIC 9(7).
       05 CLIENT-TOTAL-AMT      PIC S9(12).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 WS-EOF-SORTED    PIC A(1).
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       PERFORM SORT-INPUT-FILE.
       PERFORM GENERATE-TOTALS.
   
       GOBACK.

   SORT-INPUT-FILE.
       SORT TMP-FILE
       ON ASCENDING KEY TMP-CLIENT
           USING TX-FILE GIVING SORTED-FILE.

   GENERATE-TOTALS.
       OPEN INPUT SORTED-FILE.
       OPEN OUTPUT TOTALS-FILE.
  
  * FIRST RECORD MUST BE PROCESSED DIFFERENTLY
  * AS CLIENT-CLIENT IS NOT INITIALIZED YET
       READ SORTED-FILE
           AT END
               MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-SORTED.
       PERFORM NEW-CLIENT.
       PERFORM INCREMENT-TOTALS.

  * LOOP FOR ALL REMAINING RECORDS
       PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF-SORTED = 'Y'
           READ SORTED-FILE
               AT END
                   MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-SORTED
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM PROCESS-RECORD
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM.
       PERFORM FINISH-CLIENT.

       CLOSE SORTED-FILE, TOTALS-FILE.

   PROCESS-RECORD.
       IF TXN-CLIENT EQUAL CLIENT-CLIENT THEN
  *        SAME CLIENT
           PERFORM INCREMENT-TOTALS
       ELSE
  *        THIS RECORD BELONGS TO NEXT CLIENT
           PERFORM FINISH-CLIENT
           PERFORM NEW-CLIENT
           PERFORM INCREMENT-TOTALS
       END-IF.

   INCREMENT-TOTALS.
       ADD 1 TO CLIENT-TXN-CNT
       ADD TXN-AMOUNT TO CLIENT-TOTAL-AMT.
   
   NEW-CLIENT.
       MOVE TXN-CLIENT TO CLIENT-CLIENT.
       MOVE 0 TO CLIENT-TXN-CNT.
       MOVE 0 TO CLIENT-TOTAL-AMT.
      
   FINISH-CLIENT.
       WRITE BATCH-REC.
   
   END PROGRAM TOTALS.
```